# Engine.Razor.RunCompile Error

Tags: c#, razor, razorengine

**Scenario**

I use template with Engine Razor. I have piece of code like this:

```
if (Engine.Razor.IsTemplateCached("template", null))
{
    htmlBody = Engine.Razor.Run("template", null, email);
}
else
{
    htmlBody = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "template", null, email);
}
```

**Problem**

But I receive error in else:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The same key was already used for another template!'
```

**CONTEXT** Error occurs after:

```
RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateParsingException
```

E.g i give bad templete and received above error(Template). Next i gave proper template and received error InvalidOperationEx. it seems that after first exception my template is saved, but

```
Engine.Razor.IsTemplateCached("template", null
```

returns false. I suppose to delete template from cache but it is impossible.

Comment: At which line, please?

Comment: sorry I have already edited. 
Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "template", null, email);

Comment: Any ideas, i Add context to my question.